# home page padding on css style sheets

Tags: html, css, containers, stylesheet, padding

Can someone please help me, I've been struggling with padding for my class website. My website has everything contained in the middle. I would like my logo in the top left corner, my navigation bar underneath my logo (on the left side) and for my home page I would like my design statement to remain in the middle, and I'm not sure why the footer line is not going across the whole page.

CSS Style sheet:

```
body
{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-color:#333;
text-align:left;
background-image:url(../images/images/contemporary_china_2/contemporary_china_2.png);
padding-left:300px;
padding-bottom:200px;
}

#container{
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:right;
}

#header{
height:100px;
margin: 10px;


}
#logo {
    float:left;
    padding-left:1px;
    padding-top:1px;
}
#nav{
    width:300px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-left:100px;
}

#content { 
width:600px;
overflow:auto;
margin:30px;
height:100%;

} 


#footer {
    clear:both;
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px;
    margin:15px;
    border-top:1px solid #ff9933;

}


.work-image {
    width:460px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#ff9933;
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.work-text {
    width:220px;
    float:left;
}

/*  Navigation */
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
#nav a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active {
    background-color:rgba(255,153,102,1);
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
.active {
    background-color:#ffb76a;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:1b1b1b;
}

/*Font */.
#footer p {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
#feature h2{
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
h2 {
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding-left;10px;
}
```

Here is the source code sorry for the delay:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta name="description" content="designing is limitless"
<meta name="keywords" content="cupcakery, designing, creativity,"
<meta name="author" content="Tiffany Nicole"
<title></title>
<link href="css/2column-style.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/images 2/images/TND-logo2_03.png"/>
        </div>
        </div><!--end header-->
            <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="formdemo.html">Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--end nav-->

         <div id="content">


        <h2>DESIGN STATEMENT</h2>




         <p style="font-style:color:#FFF; font-size:115%">Designing is an outlet for me. When I'm designing I feel that my creativity is unlimited. Many individuals may believe that designing is limited to a computer, pen and paper or through their apparel. However I feel that the art of designing is limitless, and can be applied to any aspect in my life My goal is to own a Cupcakery.With my love of graphic design and culinary arts, I feel that I can incorporate both aspects into my life. My limitless creativity allows me to think outside of the box, when making cupcake designs.
         </p>


         <img src="images/images 2/images/picforwebsite_02.png"/>



         </div><!--end content -->












         <div id="footer">
         <p>Copyright © 2014 Tiffany Nicole</p>
         </div><!--end footer -->



    </div><!--end container-->







    </div><!--end container-->
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-57389036-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please make a fiddle or add html

Comment: 4 comments that say the same thing. Should have just upvoted the original comment.

Comment: @RedShift I added the source code html. sorry about the delay

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I added the html sorry about the delay

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't specifically required to write your own css, using something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) will probably save you a lot of time and effort. There is plenty of documentation and pre-existing templates that will most likely suits your needs.

Removing the main contents of [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/), and adding a logo and footer sounds pretty similar to your description.